# Unable to import compiled javascript file from Emscripten for WebAssembly (C++ wrriten) to React

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten, emcc

Hi I've compiled the C++ file via **emcc** (emscripten frontends). The output I expected is one **.wasm file** and **.js file** to implement javascript.

I build React application which try to import WebAssembly via .js module like below. (*./wasm/dist/my-module* is .js module compiled by emcc)

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import myModule from './wasm/dist/my-module'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    myModule().then((output: unknown) => console.log(output))
  }, [])

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Docker Wasm Builder.</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is the console in chrome expresses error **"file:// protocol not allow"** which is strange. Because I already build it and run the output in webserver (nginx).
[error from google chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z58kr.png)

*I already tried to create a standalone .html file and import my .js module (from emcc compiler). It worked fine but not in React.

My emcc script

```
emcc \
${OPTIMIZE} \
--bind \
--no-entry \
-s STRICT=1 \
-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 \
-s MALLOC=emmalloc \
-s MODULARIZE=1 \
-s EXPORT_ES6=1 \
-s ENVIRONMENT=web \
-o ./my-module.js \
src/wasm/my-module.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/bobbiec/react-wasm-demo). Basically, compile into -o *something*.**mjs** and add -s SINGLE_FILE=1. This will give you a single .mjs instead of a regular pair of .js and  .wasm, avoiding all the trouble.